# Use Linq to statistics data with average

Tags: c#, linq, average

I have a class named HardwarePerformance contain these fields:   time,cpuUsagePercent,memoryUsagePercent,diskUsage,diskRead,diskWrite,latency. 
    I had fill a List object to contain the not statistics data. 
    I need to calculating the average value for all these fields in a Linq command.
    I don't know how to get the average value with Linq. Follow is the code I wrote (It's incorrect of course).

```
var _hardwarePerf = (from _stats in _statsList 
                    where _time>=DateTime.Parse("2012-04-04 00:00:00")
                        &&_time<=DateTime.Parse("2012-04-04 11:00:00") 
                    select new {
                           Latency = _stats.latency, 
                           CpuUsagePercent = _stats.cpuUsagePercent, 
                           MemoryUsagePercent = _stats.memoryUsagePercent, 
                           DiskUsage = _stats.diskUsage, DiskRead = _stats.diskRead, 
                           DiskWrite = _stats.diskWrite
                    }).Average(Latency => Latency.Latency);
```

The syntax of this code is correct. But I want to calculating all the average value at the same time, how do I write my code?

Comment: Please format your code so that we don't need to scroll horizontally next time yourself.

Comment: BTW, why do your local variables start with `_`? That's a really unusual naming convention.

Comment: How is `_time` related to `_stats` since you've not written `_stats._time`?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can use "Group By" then you can use an average projection to calculate.

```
var query = from _stats in _statsList 
    group _stats by new {
               Latency = _stats.latency, 
               CpuUsagePercent = _stats.cpuUsagePercent, 
               MemoryUsagePercent = _stats.memoryUsagePercent, 
               DiskUsage = _stats.diskUsage, 
               DiskRead = _stats.diskRead, 
               DiskWrite = _stats.diskWrite

    } into myGroup
    select new {
        AverageVal = myGroup.Average(x => x.Value),
        CpuUsagePercent = myGroup.Key.CpuUsagePercent,
        ... // the rest of your projection
};
```

[LINQ Average](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5313665/c-sharp-linq-average)

Comment: And how would you use that to calculate the average of all the fields at once?

Comment: The edited code doesn't make any sense to me? What is `Value`? And your grouping by distinct values doesn't make any sense and it certainly doesn't compute the averages.

Answer (score 1):

There is no built-in method for this in LINQ. If you don't mind that you will be iterating the collection several times, and assuming an anonymous object is okay for you, you can do something like this (where `filteredStats` contains the data you want to average, probably filtered by time):

```
var averages =
    new
    {
        Latency = filteredStats.Average(x => x.Latency),
        CpuUsagePercent = filteredStats.Average(x => x.CpuUsagePercent),
        …
    };
```

If that's not what you want, you will probably have to calculate the averages on your own.

Comment: I programming like this style right now, thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

The following calculates all the averages in one iteration, although it's a lot of code.

Note that I've assumed `time` is a property on your stats object, otherwise your `select where time` doesn't make much sense.

```
var _hardwareAccumulator =
    _statsList
        .Where(s =>
            s.time >= DateTime.Parse("2012-04-04 00:00:00") &&
            s.time <= DateTime.Parse("2012-04-04 11:00:00"))
        .Aggregate(
            new
            {
                count = 0,
                cpuUsagePercent = 0.0,
                memoryUsagePercent = 0.0,
                diskUsage = 0.0,
                diskRead = 0.0
            },
            (acc, s) =>
                new
                {
                    count = acc.count + 1,
                    cpuUsagePercent =
                        acc.cpuUsagePercent + s.cpuUsagePercent,
                    memoryUsagePercent =
                        acc.memoryUsagePercent + s.memoryUsagePercent,
                    diskUsage =
                        acc.diskUsage + s.diskUsage,
                    diskRead =
                        acc.diskRead + s.diskRead
                }
            );
var _hardwarePerf = new
{
    cpuUsagePercent =
        _hardwareAccumulator.cpuUsagePercent / _hardwareAccumulator.count,
    memoryUsagePercent =
        _hardwareAccumulator.memoryUsagePercent / _hardwareAccumulator.count,
    diskUsage =
        _hardwareAccumulator.diskUsage / _hardwareAccumulator.count,
    diskRead =
        _hardwareAccumulator.diskRead / _hardwareAccumulator.count
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You either nee to do that in separate statements or you could do it in this not very intuitive way:

```
var averages = statsList.Where(s => s.time >= new DateTime(2012, 4, 4) && s.time <= new DateTime(2012, 4, 04, 11, 0, 0))
            .GroupBy(s => 1)
            .Select(grp => new
            {
                Latency = grp.Average(s => s.latency),
                CpuUsagePercent = grp.Average(s => s.cpuUsagePercent),
                MemoryUsagePercent = grp.Average(s => s.memoryUsagePercent),
                DiskUsage = grp.Average(s => s.diskUsage),
                DiskRead = grp.Average(s => s.diskRead),
                DiskWrite = grp.Average(s => s.diskWrite)
            }).FirstOrDefault();
```

Note that `.GroupBy(s => 1)` just to be able to calculate the average for each property. Also note that i've removed the underlines from your property names and added *time* to your class.

The other approach is easier to read:

```
var theStats = statsList.Where(s => s.time >= new DateTime(2012, 4, 4) && s.time <= new DateTime(2012, 4, 04, 11, 0, 0));
var Latency = theStats.Average(s => s.latency);
var CpuUsagePercent = theStats.Average(s => s.cpuUsagePercent);
// ....
```

Comment: How is this different from just filtering the stats on `time`, then making an anoynous object with all the averages from the filtered list? What does grouping achieve?

Comment: @Rawling: The grouping enables to select the anonymous type with all averages in one query.

Comment: @Rawling: I'm afraid you haven't understood the core problem  of this question. You cannot filter on time and then select **all** _averages_ only **1**. Therefore i've added the pseudo-group.

Comment: I'm aware that a standard Linq `Average` can only get you one average. I fail to see the utility in performing a dummy grouping and select purely so you can get all the averages in a single WTF-inducing Linq statement. I agree that your second solution is the simplest, easiest-to-read way to get all the averages, and really should be the accepted answer given that the OP apparently doesn't care about iterating through the results more than once.